ESS for R: how to achieve a simple indentation of 4 with respect to previous line, disregarding parentheses?
[ESS version: 20240803.1733,
Emacs version: 29.4]
I would like to indent R code without alignment to open brackets of any kind (no matter whether they are associated with functions, if-statements, and similar). In other words, I'd like to indent simply by increasing the indentation by 4 spaces with respect to the previous indentation.
As an example, instead of
    } else if (a >= 1 &&
               b <= 2) {

I'd like to have
    } else if (a >= 1 &&
        b <= 2) {

In order to achieve this I've set ess-style to 'OWN and customized ess-own-style-list to the following (as seen in the customization buffer):
Alist:
INS DEL Key: ess-indent-offset
            Value: 4
INS DEL Key: ess-offset-arguments
            Value: prev-line
INS DEL Key: ess-offset-arguments-newline
            Value: prev-line
INS DEL Key: ess-offset-block
            Value: prev-line
INS DEL Key: ess-offset-continued
            Value: straight
INS DEL Key: ess-align-continuations-in-calls
            Value: t
INS DEL Key: ess-align-blocks
            Value: nil
INS DEL Key: ess-indent-from-lhs
            Value: nil
INS DEL Key: ess-indent-from-chain-start
            Value: t
INS DEL Key: ess-indent-with-fancy-comments
            Value: t

trying to understand the description of the individual variables and reading answers to related questions such as this. Yet the first, parenthesis-aligned form of indentation persists – note that I've re-opened the buffer, restarded Emacs, and also called (ess-set-style 'OWN), but to no avail.
Which of my customized settings above is wrong? Or is there some kind of bug?
(It should be noted that ESS changed many internal variable names in recent years, so many similar questions & answers on StackExchange are somewhat outdated.)
Cheers!
